# Nano-like editor that support Ctrl+Backspace and Ctrl+Arrow keys

Tags: linux, vim, nano

Does anybody know of a nano-like editor that supports <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> keys? Like in Windows, where you can delete and navigate words.

I have been trying to learn the basics of Vim for the last couple of months. While it's useful, I find it ineffective (for me) moving in and out of insert mode. Especially for quick edits.

I need it to work in Linux terminal, like nano does.

Comment: You could very well try `emacs`, if you don't get into modal editing.

Comment: How about remapping a key combination to speed up the shift from Insert to Edit mode? Like, perhaps, Ctrl + Space ? http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_map_keys_in_vim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Joe's Own Editor](http://joe-editor.sourceforge.net/) or [ne, the nice editor](http://ne.dsi.unimi.it/).

Or take the time to learn Vim's basics in normal mode:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> = `w`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> = `e`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> = `ve` then `e` and `e`…
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> = `vb` then `b` and `b`…
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> = `db`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> = `dw`

and in insert mode:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> = `<C-w>`

It's shorter and you don't even need to keep a finger on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>whatever</kbd>.

Comment: and ctrl+backspace would be `de`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's available in your environment, but a useful piece of software for the terminal is [Midnight Commander](http://www.midnight-commander.org/) (their site uses a self-signed certificate, so don't worry about this). It has a built-in editor with a lot of shortcuts, syntax highlighting, etc. and its behaviour is *like in Windows*.